# How do I extract data residing in d3 svg components using slimerjs?

Tags: javascript, svg, slimerjs

I just started using slimerJS few days back. I would like to know about how can I use slimerjs for handling SVG components? We are making use of graphs for representing various datas  in our web application , it will change dynamically depending on the input from the client.

For the testing purpose I have to extract data bounded by  each d3 svg elements from the graph portion and have to verify its data with the real data in the database . 
Instead of taking screen shots of the svg components , **Is there any better method to verify the data represented by the SVG elements (in the web application) with the original data in the database using slimerjs ?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `slimer.js` is but from a quick look at their webpage, it looks like some sort of wrapper around `phantom.js`.  As such, you have access to the DOM for the page your are manipulating and since you can access the elements, you can get the bound data of any `d3` svg element (they are properties of the DOM element).  For instance, say I have a pie chart [like on this page](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235).  The data value of the first pie slice would be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('arc')[0].__data__.value
```

Or say a line chart [like this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245).  The data array is under:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0].__data__
```